# Generic - Compiler warning CS0693 or error

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-errors, warnings

I have my generic class and two methods that accept as argument a delegate (generic or not)

```
public sealed class MyClass<TResult>
{
   public MyClass ContinueWith(ThreadInfo.Parameterized arg)
   {
   }

   public MyClass<TResult> ContinueWith<TResult>(ThreadInfo<TResult>.Parameterized arg)
   {
   }
}
```

Where:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
}
```

I have the [Compiler Warning (level3) CS0693](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ah54ze5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but if I remove `<TResult>` from the second method:

```
public MyClass<TResult> ContinueWith(ThreadInfo<TResult>.Parameterized arg)
```

I can't use this method anymore, if I try I get a compiler error because the compiler thinks I want to use the first method.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it sounds like you *really* want:

```
public MyClass<TResult> ContinueWith(ThreadInfo<TResult>.Parameterized arg)
```

In other words, using the `TResult` parameter declared at the *type* level.

If you really want it to be a generic method (i.e. introducing a new type parameter) you have to give it a different name:

```
public MyClass<T2> ContinueWith<T2>(ThreadInfo<T2>.Parameterized arg)
```

(It's possible that you may want to *return* a `MyClass<TResult>` here, or something similar - we don't really know what you're trying to achieve, which makes it hard to give detailed help.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different parameter names. So this depends on what do you want to achieve.

I think you need something like this, where the return type is of type `MyClass<TResult>` and you can choose the type for `ThreadInfo<>`:

```
public MyClass<TResult> ContinueWith<T1>(ThreadInfo<T1>.Parameterized arg)
{
   //...
}
```

Or if you want to choose the type only when you create an instance of your object:

```
public MyClass<TResult> ContinueWith(ThreadInfo<TResult>.Parameterized arg)
{
   //...
}
```